# How can I prove this is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is the following equation a subspace in $R^3$? $$3x + y^2 + z = 0$$

I know that it must contain the zero vector, must be closed under addition and multiplication.

I can verify the zero vector clause. But how do I mathematically prove the last 2 without a specific example?

Comment: a counterexample -- e.g.,$(0,1,-1)$ is a solution but $2(0,1,-1)$ is not -- suffices to prove that solutions of that equation are not a subspace (note the non-linear $y^2$ term)

Comment: Picking nits: The _equation_ can’t possibly be a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Its solution set is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT a subspace.  The key is in the word "linear" in "Linear Algebra".  $3x+ y^2+ z= 0$.  $y^2$ is not "linear".  We can show that explicitly by giving a counter-example (while a "specific example" is not sufficient to prove a general theorem, one "counter example" is sufficient to disprove it).

In order that this be a sub-space, it must be "closed under scalar multiplication".  That is, if v is in the subspace so is av for any scalar, a.  v= (-1, 2, -1) is in the subspace because 3(-1)+ 4- 1= -4+ 4= 0.  Let a= 3.  av= (-3, 6, -3) and 3(-3)+ 36- 3= 36- 12= 24, not 0, so av is NOT in the subspace.